# Can't open CSV file: no implicit conversion of StringIO into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want to read a CSV file produced by an export from one of my controllers. Here is the simple code:

```
def export_houses

  houses_file = open("http://127.0.0.1:3000/houses/export.csv")

  houses = CSV.open(houses_file, 'r:bom|utf-8', { headers: true })

  ...

end
```

The problem occurs on the `CSV.open` line, where I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of StringIO into String
from /Users/htaidirt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1256:in `initialize'
```

`houses_file` is correctly found. It's a `StringIO` class, but I wanted a `File` class to use with `CSV.open`.

Do you have an idea how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried 'houses_file = File.open("...")' or directly houses = CSV.open("http://127.0.0.1:3000/houses/export.csv", 'r:bom|utf-8', { headers: true }) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, both solutions result in the following error: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://127.0.0.1:3000/houses/export.csv`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can read a csv file from http server like this :

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/houses/export.csv'
houses = CSV.new(open(url), :headers => :first_row)
```

or you can parse it with parse method

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/houses/export.csv'
houses = CSV.parse(open(url).read, :headers => true)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it saved my lot of time :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .string at the end of open(uri)

[StringIO to String Conversion](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-string)

```
def export_houses

  houses_file = open("http://127.0.0.1:3000/houses/export.csv").string

  houses = CSV.open(houses_file, 'r:bom|utf-8', { headers: true })

  ...

end
```

Comment: Use [`read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-read) instead of `string`. `open` returns a handle than can be a StringIO or an IO. In either case, `read` will cause the contents to be read and returned. And, at that point, `CSV.parse` would be the appropriate method to use because the content would be contained in a string.

Comment: This gives me the following: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'string' for #<Tempfile:0x0000010477bb40>`...

Comment: We are near the solution. Using `.read` gives a `String`, how to convert to `File`?